Locust: control the user creation sequence of multiple user classes
I have two user classes:

SyncUser
NormalUser

with the following code:
class syncUser(HttpUser):
    host = '<hostname>'
    def on_start(self):
        self.userId = getsyncPullUser()
        self.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

    @task
    def SyncUser(self):
        timeout=10
        params = {
            "timeout":timeout,
        }
        while True:
            response = self.client.get("/sync/api", headers = self.headers, params = params, name="GET_sync/api")


class NormalUser(HttpUser):
    host = '<hostname>'

    def on_start(self):
        self.userId = getuser()
        self.headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }

    @task
    def getmessages(self):
        params = {
            "status":"ACCEPTED",
            "source":"postman"
        }

        self.client.get("/<api>", headers = self.headers, params = params, name="GET /<api>")



I want to create NormalUser after SyncUser. This is done to make sure the userIds assigned to NormalUser(using getuser()) are a subset of users assigned to SyncUser (using getsyncPullUser()).
Need help in how to do this.
If there is a way to run multiple tasks simultaneously, that also solves my problem, as I will run the syncUser function in parallel and I won't need a new class.

Hi aa! Your question is a little long and hard to read. Can you clarify and make it shorter? I'd love to help you but I don't want to resort to guessing at what you mean...

Hi @Cyberwiz I have tried to include some code and make it simpler. Please let me know which part is difficult to understand.

Here's an example of how to do things in parallel in one user: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/increase-performance.html#concurrency I think it works for HttpUser as well, but if not, try switching to FastHttpUser

for my requirement, the above solution might not work. example scenario:
Task1 : runs indefinitely
Task2: start and complete.  start again when scheduled
Task3: start and complete.  start again when scheduled
So the concurrency I would want is task1 runs indefinitely, but task2 and task3 can switch amongst themselves, according to the weights assigned to them .

You could start an entirely separate greenlet in on_start that does ”task1” forever (possibly interrupting it in on_stop)

This worked for me, Thanks
